# Find $T\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}, dx^l\right)$ for a tensor of type ${1}\choose{1}$ on $T_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

So say I have the tensor of type ${1}\choose{1}$, with $T \in T_p(\mathbb{R}^n) \otimes T_p^*(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where $$T = T^{a}_{b} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^a} \otimes dx^b$$ summed over all $a, b$.

> *Problem:* Find $T\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}, dx^l\right)$

Wouldn't $T$ take as an input (when identified with it's corresponding multilinear map) in its first argument a one-form and in it's second argument a tangent vector?

Said more concretely since we have $$T_p(\mathbb{R}^n) \otimes T_p^*(\mathbb{R}^n) \cong L\left(T_p^*(\mathbb{R}^n) \ ,\  T_p(\mathbb{R}^n); \mathbb{R}\right)$$ we can identify $T$ with a multilinear map $$T(\omega, X_p) = \left(T^{a}_b  \frac{\partial}{\partial x^a} \otimes dx^b\right)(\omega, X_p) = T^a_b \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}(\omega) \cdot {dx}^b(X_p)\right)$$

(Also note that strictly $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}$ doesn't take as inputs one-forms but we can identify it with an element of the bidual $T_p^{**}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which does so we can do this without harm.

But the problem states that we need to find $T\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}, dx^l\right)$ , shouldn't it instead be to find $T\left(dx^l, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\right)$?

Comment: It's just a convention. If you keep the offer, no matters which is first. But yes, if you write first the tensor product of vectors, $T$ should take a $1$-form in its first argument.

Comment: @Dog_69 What do you mean by "keep the offer"?

Comment: It's a typo sorry. Keep the order. Write always vectors or $1$-forms first.